# Unload unsupported/incompatible Project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

On a  project that is not loaded because of a missing addin/application the "Unload Project" menu item is disabled on the projects context menu. A "migration error report" is shown each time when loading the solution where "lightwight solution load" is not enabled. So there seems to be no way to tell VS to ignore these projects while loading the solution. Not all members of the team have the licence for these addins (Sandcastle, WIX, ...) or do not want to install them.

Comment: SandCastle and Wix are *open-source*. You don't need a license, just install them

Comment: As for removing the projects, just remove them. After the migration, open the migrated solution and simply remove the projects that can't be loaded

Comment: "Unload project" is disabled because the project did not get loaded.  No lack of duh there.  Talk to the boss, tell him that the team needs a build engineer.